# Bit Flipping - How is the answer -61?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

I am following this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bitwise_operators.htm
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm

I am confused how A which starts out as: A = 0011 1100 (60 in decimal) can become -61 when all the bits are flipped with the ~ operator.

I understand that `~A` will become: 1100 0011. From my calculations, this binary number 1100 0011 equals 195 in decimal. However the answer is -61 in base ten according to the c programming language and the tutorial.

Could someone please help me understand?

Thank-you for reading this question.

Comment: 195-256 = -61: two's complement on a 8-bit type

Comment: Please show the exact code you are running so that we can try to reproduce the problem instead of guessing.

Comment: This should not be surprising since (by definition) `-x = ~x + 1` and therefore `~x = -x - 1`

Comment: @merlin2011 I am trying to do this by hand. The code is in one of the links above though. I wrote it in an IDE and compiled it. Then ran it and the result was -61.

Comment: [What is “2's Complement”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1049722/995714)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Answer (score 1):

When you flip the bits of a signed positive value, you flip the higher bit as well (on any type).

So when you print the value, you get a negative value.

With an unsigned 8-bit type, you'll get what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int x = 60;
   printf("%d\n",~x);
   char y = x;
   printf("%d\n",~y);
   unsigned char z = x;
   printf("%u\n",(unsigned char)~z);

   return 0;
}
```

result:

```
-61
-61
195
```

for integer & char, you get `-61`, but if you use an unsigned char, you get `195`, higher bit is used for value not for sign.

`1100 0011` is `195` when considering all bits having the same meaning (unsigned).

`1100 0011` signed is `100 0011=64+2+1=67` - `2^7=128` = `-61`

Comment: Awesome. But can you explain how I would get this by hand? Like how does 1100 0011 become -61 when it seems to mean 195? That is interesting how the unsigned char becomes 195 when flipped just as I get when I flip the bits by hand and then figure out the base ten value based on that. :)

Comment: @user3870315 you also got -61 by hand, just interpret those bits as an 8bit signed integer.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that @harold. 0_o

Comment: @user3870315 almost the same as usual, but use a negative weight for the top bit, so -128 for 8 bits, you'd get -128 + 64 + 2 + 1

Comment: That is an excellent answer @harold. Thank-you for chiming in. :))))))