# Hexadecimal subtraction

Tags: math, hex

How come

> `E9EF - FDBA`

is equal to
`FFFF FFFF FFFF EC35`?

[image]

Although according to [this](http://www.calculator.net/hex-calculator.html?number1=e9ef&c2op=-&number2=fdba&calctype=op&x=53&y=20) calculator answer is

> -13CB

which is what I got when I solved question myself. I want to know how is

> `FFFF FFFF FFFF EC35`

correct answer?

Comment: Have you heard of twos complement

Comment: @EdHeal yes, can you please explain a bit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is “2's Complement”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement)

Comment: Why not just google it?

Comment: Read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement - a good explaination

Comment: @EdHeal which one of two is correct answer?

Comment: They are both correct

Comment: negative value in twos complement in hex is `0xFFFFFFFFFFFblablabla` as your calculator does not handle signs it considered the result to be positive ....