# What else can the less than operator mean in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am learning bit algorithm and saw the equation that finds the max of two values:

```
r = x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y)); // max(x, y)
```

The explanation says this equation will find the max without using comparison and "if x < y, then -(x < y) will be all ones". I cannot comprehend what the explanation means because I see a "less than" operator in the equation and if that is an less than operator, (x < y) should return only one bit of data. Therefore, for the explanation to make sense, the sign "<" cannot be the less than operator. I looked at the list of C operators and did not find other meanings for operator "<". Can someone tell me what does the operator "<" do in this equation? Thanks!

Comment: It *is* the “less than” operator. `x < y` is either 0 or 1. `-(x < y)` is either 0 or −1.

Comment: I see, so -(x<y) is just used to generate a mask. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It doesn't find the max "without using comparison", it just uses a comparison in a less straightforward way... so the explanation is questionable.  Without using a *conditional*, maybe...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very tricky code. The truth is that C does not have any Boolean type: it uses integer instead: `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`.

Therefore `-(x<y)` means

- `0` if `x≥y`
- `-1` if `x<y`

It is then used as a bit mask.

**Edit**

As suggested by Jonathan Leffler in comments, C has now a _Bool.
I made this small program to check what is it and how it is used:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {  
  _Bool bFalse = 1>2;    
  printf("size of _Bool: %lu\nsize of comparison result: %lu\n", sizeof(bFalse), sizeof(1>2));
  return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
size of _Bool: 1
size of comparison result: 4
```

In other words `_Bool` is one byte (a `char`), but it is not used as a result of Boolean comparisons (my compiler generates 4 bytes, that is, an `int`)

Note: tested with Clang on an Intel processor.

**Edit:** fix the types as kindly suggested in comments (and after checking the clang IR)

Comment: The truth is that C has had a Boolean type, `_Bool` (and `bool` if you include `<stdbool.h>`) since the 1999 standard.

Comment: `_Bool` is a native type, not an unsigned char or whatever.  You could read the documentation for it instead of trying to guess its behaviour

Comment: The result of a comparison is of type `int`, not `unsigned int`. Please don't guess.

Answer (score 2):

"if x < y, then -(x < y) will be all ones"

This is because, if x is less than y, condition evaluates to true (equal to 1). Notice the negetive sign before comparison, it makes the "1" of comparison result as "-1". In binary world, -1 has an all 1 representation, see [Two's_complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement). Example: 1111 1111 = -1.

However, if x > y, you get a -0 which is again all zero in binary.

Here, '<' is only a "x is_less_than y" comparison check, a logical operator.

Comment: C implementations do not all use 2's complement. So we could say that the OP code relies on being run on a 2's complement implementation.