# Packing bytes into a long with |= is giving unexpected results

Tags: java

I am trying to concatenate my byte[] data into a long variable. But for some reason, the code is not working as I expected.

I have this byte array which maximum size will be 8 bytes which are 64 bits, the same size a Long variable has so I am trying to concatenate this array into the long variable.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    byte[] data = new byte[]{
            (byte)0xD4,(byte)0x11,(byte)0x92,(byte)0x55,(byte)0xBC,(byte)0xF9
            };

    Long l = 0l;

    for (int i =0; i<6; i++){
        l |= data[i];           
        l <<=8;
        String lon = String.format("%064d", new BigInteger(Long.toBinaryString((long)l)));
        System.out.println(lon);
    }




}
```

The results are:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101010000000000
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111110101000001000100000000
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111001001000000000
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111100100100101010100000000
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011110000000000
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100100000000
```

When the final result should be something like

```
111111111111111110101000001000110010010010101011011110011111001
```

which is 0xD4,0x11,0x92,0x55,0xBC,0xF9

Comment: swap the first two lines in the for loop, and no reason to use Long intead of long here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`byte` in Java is signed, and when you do `long |= byte`, the `byte`'s value is promoted and the sign bit is extended, which essentially sets all those higher bits to 1 if the `byte` was a negative value.

You can do this instead:

```
 l |= (data[i] & 255)
```

To force it into an `int` and kill the sign before it's then promoted to a `long`. [Here is an example of this happening](http://ideone.com/YkRvqb).

---

### Details

*Prerequisite: If the term "sign bit" does not make sense to you, then you must read [What is “2's Complement”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement) first. I will not explain it here.*

Consider:

```
byte b = (byte)0xB5;
long n = 0l;

n |= b; // analogous to your l |= data[i]
```

Note that `n |= b` is exactly equivalent to `n = n | b` ([JLS 15.26.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)) so we'll look at that.

So first `n | b` must be evaluated. But, `n` and `b` are different types.

According to [JLS 15.22.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1):

> When both operands of an operator &, ^, or | are of a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive integral type, binary numeric promotion is first performed on the operands (§5.6.2).

Both operands *are* convertible to primitive integral types, so we consult [5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) to see what happens next. The relevant rules here are:

> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - ...
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `long`, the other is converted to `long`.
>    - ...

Ok, well, `n` is `long`, so according to this `b` must be now be converted to `long` using the rules specified in [5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2). The relevant rule there is:

> A widening conversion of a signed integer value to an integral type T simply sign-extends the two's-complement representation of the integer value to fill the wider format.

Well `byte` is a signed integer value and its being converted to a `long`, so according to this the sign bit (highest bit) is simply extended to the left to fill the space. So this is what happens in our example (imagine 64 bits here  I'm just saving space):

```
b = (byte)0xB5                     10110101
b widened to long  111 ... 1111111110110101
n                  000 ... 0000000000000000
n | b              111 ... 1111111110110101
```

And so `n | b` evaluates to `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFB5`, *not* `0x00000000000000B5`. That is, when that sign bit is extended and the OR operation is applied, you've got all those `1`'s there essentially overwriting all of the bits from the previous bytes you've OR'd in, and your final results, then, are incorrect.

It's all the result of `byte` being signed and Java requiring `long | byte` to be converted to `long | long` prior to performing the calculation.

If you're unclear on the implicit conversions happening here, here is the explicit version:

```
n = n | (long)b;
```

---

### Details of workaround

So now consider the "workaround":

```
byte b = (byte)0xB5;
long n = 0l;

n |= (b & 255);
```

So here, we evaluate `b & 255` first.

So from [JLS 3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) we see that the literal `255` is of type `int`.

This leaves us with `byte & int`. The rules are about the same as above although we invoke a slightly different case from [5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`.

So as per those rules `byte` must be converted to an `int` first. So in this case we have:

```
(byte)0xB5                                10110101
promote to int    11111111111111111111111110110101  (sign extended)
255               00000000000000000000000011111111
&                 00000000000000000000000010110101
```

And the result is an `int`, which is signed, but as you can see, *now its a positive number and its sign bit is 0*.

Then the next step is to evaluate `n | the byte we just converted`. So again as per the above rules the new `int` is widened to a `long`, sign bit extended, but this time:

```
b & 255                    00000000000000000000000010110101
convert to long  000 ... 0000000000000000000000000010110101
n                000 ... 0000000000000000000000000000000000
n | (b & 255)    000 ... 0000000000000000000000000010110101
```

And now we get the intended value.

**The workaround works by converting `b` to an `int` as an intermediate step and setting the high 24 bits to 0, thus letting us convert *that* to a `long` without the original sign bit getting in the way.**

If you're unclear on the implicit conversions happening here, here is the explicit version:

```
n = n | (long)((int)b & 255);
```

---

### Other stuff

And also like maraca mentions in comments, swap the first two lines in your loop, otherwise you end up shifting the whole thing 8 bits too far to the left at the end (that's why your low 8 bits are zero).

Also I notice that your expected final result is padded with leading `1`s. If that's what you want at the end you can start with `-1L` instead of `0L` (in addition to the other fixes).