# C Convert a Short Int to Unsigned Short

Tags: c, unsigned-integer

A short int in C contains 16 bits and the first bit represents whether or not the value is negative or positive. I have a C program that is as follows:

```
int main() {
    short int v;
    unsigned short int uv;
    v = -20000;
    uv = v;
    printf("\nuv = %hu\n", uv);
    return 0;
}
```

Since the value of **v** is negative I know the first bit of the variable is a 1. So I expect the output of the program to equal **uv = 52,768** b/c **20,000 + (2^15) = 52,768**.

Instead I am getting **uv = 45536** as the output. What part of my logic is incorrect?

Comment: Numbers are stored in 2's complement (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). So the largest unsigned number (0xFFFF) is actually -1

Comment: Negative numbers are not represented by simply setting the last bit. They are reresented as binary complement., i.e. all bits negated plus one. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement

Comment: @Marian This post was incredibly useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing can be explained by the conversion rules of C:

> **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
>
> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> 2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.

(This quote is from C99.)

`-20000` can't be represented by an `unsigned short` because it's negative. The target type is unsigned, so the value is converted by repeatedly adding 65536 (which is `USHORT_MAX + 1`) until it is in range: `-20000 + 65536` is exactly `45536`.

Note that this behavior is mandated by the C standard and has nothing to do with how negative numbers are actually represented in memory (in particular, it works the same way even on machines using [sign/magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation) or [ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement)).

Comment: The modulo behaviour is mandated by the standard - `USHORT_MAX` being `65536` is not (it could be larger)