# Range for int when using binary literal

Tags: java

Consider the following code:

```
int x1 = 0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_111; // binary for 2147483647
System.out.println(x1); // prints 2147483647

int x2 = 2147483648; // The literal 2147483648 of type int is out of range

// x3 is binary representation for 2147483648
int x3 = 0b1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000; // accepted without any compile errors
System.out.println(x3); // prints -2147483648 

// x4 is binary representation for 4294967295
int x4 = 0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111; // long value: 4294967295
System.out.println(x4); // prints -1

int x5 = 0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1; // The literal 0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1 of type int is out of range
```

The `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `2147483647` and compiler accepts any `int` in that range, and throws an error when this value goes beyond `2147483647`. However, the int `x3`(int: -1, long: 2147483648) and `x4`(int: -1, long: 4294967295) in above snippet is accepted without any errors but throws errors in case of `x5`.

First question: Why the compiler did not complain about the range of `x3`?

Second question: If the value of `x3` and `x4` is accepted without any errors, why does it throw errors in case of `x5`?

Comment: `int` is in java a 32-bit signed [two's-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) integer. You can read more about this in [The Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1-700)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

> Why the compiler did not complain about the range of x3?

Because it fits in 32 bits, and the Java Language Specification (JLS) says that literal is valid when it does.

> If the value of x3 and x4 is accepted without any errors, why does it throw errors in case of x5?

Because it doesn't fits in 32 bits, given that it is 33 bits long.

---

**Comment on Code Style**

You should insert the `_` separators in a binary literal where the [nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) boundaries are, so instead of `0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_111` it should be `0b111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111`.

That then correctly represents that it is the first nibble that's missing a digit. It also makes it directly comparable to the hex representation, e.g. `0x7F_FF_FF_FF`.

Your way of inserting `_` is very confusing.

---

**Long answer**

In Java, numbers formatted using [`Integer.toBinaryString​(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString-int-), [`Integer.toHexString​(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString-int-), and [`Integer.toOctalString​(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toOctalString-int-) are formatted as *unsigned* numbers.

This fits the Java integer literal syntax as defined by JLS [3.10.1. Integer Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1), which states:

> It is a compile-time error if a hexadecimal, octal, or binary `int` literal does not **fit in 32 bits**.

Since `0b1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000` and `0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111`, as well as their hex counterparts `0x80_00_00_00` and `0xFF_FF_FF_FF`, all fit in 32 bits, they are valid `int` literals.

If you print them using the methods above, they match the literal, even though they would all print `-1` if printed as a (signed) decimal:

```java
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111));
System.out.println(Integer.toOctalString(037_777_777_777));
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(0xFF_FF_FF_FF));
```

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
37777777777
ffffffff
```

Comment: The only part that is missing in this answer is why does `x3` and `x4` have negative values.

Comment: @Edwardth Not missing in answer, since it wasn't asked for in question.

Comment: @Andreas it's not directly asked, but you can see that the asker is a bit confused about the fact that the binary representation of `4294967295` doesn't throw an exception, since it seems like the value goes beyond `2147483647` and this should throw one.

Answer (score 2):

The first bit for both `x3` and `x4` is `1`, hence they are treated as negative numbers. They are both declared as 32 bit numbers, so they fit an `int` data type and the compiler doesn't complain. `x5` gives error because you are attempting to assign 33 bits to a 32 bit data type, so it overflows.

Comment: But it looks like `0b1` is `1` in base 10

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Where did you write `0b1`?

Comment: `int x = 0b1;` and `int x = 0b11;` are valid, if you need to change the bit, you can use `int x1 = -0b1;` and `int x1 = -0b11;` resp

Comment: `int x = 0b1;` and `int x = -0b1;` are `+1` and `-1`. The first bit does not look like sign bit.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Oh, now I got it. `0b1` is accepted because 1 is treated as the least significant bit. `0b1` means `0b0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001`. `0b11` means `0b0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0011`

Comment: Can you point me to some link where I can read about them in more detail?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I'll search some asap

Answer (score 0):

The primitive `int` is a 32 bit number, with the leading bit being the sign of the integer, so when you used int for `2147483648` you caused an overflow error. To fix your problem, use the primitives `double` or `long` for higher values.

Answer (score 0):

**[The Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) has the answer.**

[4.2. Primitive Types and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)

> The integral types are byte, short, int, and long, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers

So `int` is a 32-bit [two's-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). (Also read the great answer about: [What is “2's Complement”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1049774/4503858))

And in [3.10.1. Integer Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1-720) it shows:

> The largest positive hexadecimal, octal, and binary literals of type int - each of which represents the decimal value 2147483647 (2^31-1) - are respectively:
>
> - 0x7fff_ffff,
> - 0177_7777_7777, and
> - 0b0111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111
>
> The most negative hexadecimal, octal, and binary literals of type int - each of which represents the decimal value -2147483648 (-2^31) - are respectively:
>
> - 0x8000_0000,
> - 0200_0000_0000, and
> - 0b1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000
>
> The following hexadecimal, octal, and binary literals represent the decimal value -1:
>
> - 0xffff_ffff,
> - 0377_7777_7777, and
> - 0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111
>
> **It is a compile-time error if a hexadecimal, octal, or binary int literal does not fit in 32 bits.**