# Wrong result with bitwise inclusive OR

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I can't figure out why does inclusive OR return wrong result.

```
char arr[] = { 0x0a, 0xc0 };
uint16_t n{};

n = arr[0]; // I get 0x000a here.
n = n << 8; // Shift to the left and get 0x0a00 here.
n = n | arr[1]; // But now the n value is 0xffc0 instead of 0x0ac0.
```

What is the mistake in this example? Console app, MVS Community 2017.

Comment: Please, try `n = n | (unsigned char)arr[1];`. I guess, `0xff` is caused by [sign bit extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) while converting `char` to `int`.

Comment: `arr[1] > 127` so it is a negative `char` value that is *sign-extended* on type promotion along with `uint16_t` in `n | arr[1]`.

Comment: Or change types, e.g. `unsigned char arr[] = { 0x0a, 0xc0 };`

Comment: General rule: avoid signed types when working with bitwise operations (and `char` signedness is implementation-defined); way too much stuff becomes implementation-defined (and some even undefined).

Comment: Your latest public working draft is [C++ Standard - 7.6 Integral Promotions (working draft n4741)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4741.pdf#section.7.6) (**note:** earlier drafts include it as section 4.5)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The unintended `0xff` is caused by [sign bit extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) of `0xc0`.

0xc0 = 0b11000000

Hence, the uppermost bit is set which means sign for `char` (as `signed char`).

Please, note that all arithmetic and bitwise operations in C++ work with at least `int` (or `unsigned int`). Smaller types are promoted before and clipped afterwards.

Please, note also that `char` may be signed or unsigned. That's compiler implementation dependent. Obviously, it's signed in the case of OP. To prevent the unintended sign extension, the argument has to become unsigned (early enough).

Demonstration:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  char arr[] = { '\x0a', '\xc0' };
  uint16_t n{};

  n = arr[0]; // I get 0x000a here.
  n = n << 8; // Shift to the left and get 0x0a00 here.
  n = n | arr[1]; // But now the n value is 0xffc0 instead of 0x0ac0.
  std::cout << std::hex << "n (wrong): " << n << std::endl;
  n = arr[0]; // I get 0x000a here.
  n = n << 8; // Shift to the left and get 0x0a00 here.
  n = n | (unsigned char)arr[1]; // (unsigned char) prevents sign extension
  std::cout << std::hex << "n (right): " << n << std::endl;
  return 0;

}
```

Session:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
n (wrong): ffc0
n (right): ac0
```

<kbd>Life demo on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00d59e4a500df86c)</kbd>

Note:

I had to change
`char arr[] = { 0x0a, 0xc0 };`
to
 `char arr[] = { '\x0a', '\xc0' };`
 to come around serious compiler complaints. I guess, these complaints where strongly related to this issue.

Comment: This is the correct answer, though it would probably be easier to declare `arr` as `unsigned char` entirely instead of casting the values in it every time

Comment: @Aemyl Yepp, agree but there might be a (separate) reason why it is `char`.

Comment: Well, that's true

Comment: @Aemyl If data storage is done by `std::string` then you need the `(unsigned char)` trick. I often needed it e.g. with <cctype> macros when ASCIIs above 127 are uninteresting but might kill you app otherwise.

Comment: @FrankAK AFAIK, it initializes `n` with 0. If in doubt, `uint16_t n = 0;` would work as well. (Please, note the implicit casting of `(int)0` to `uint16_t`.) ;-)

Comment: I can't compile it on G++ , got `error: expected ';' at end of declaration` error.

Answer (score 0):

You have fallen a victim to **signed integer promotion**.

When assigning `0xc0` to the second element (signed char default because of MVS) in the array, this is represented as follows:

```
arr[1] = 1100 - 0000, or in decimal -64
```

When this is cast to an `uint16_t`, it is promoted to an integer with the value `-64`. This is:

```
n = 1111 - 1111 - 1100 - 0000 = -64
```

due to the [2's complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement) implementation of integers.

Therefore:

```
n          = 1111 - 1111 - 1100 - 0000 
arr[1]     = 0000 - 0000 - 1010 - 0000 (after being promoted)

n | arr[1] = 1111 - 1111 -1110-0000 = 0xffc0
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work correctly by doing:

```
int arr[] = { 0x0a, 0xc0 };
int n{};

n = arr[0]; // I get 0x000a here.
n = n << 8; // Shift to the left and get 0x0a00 here.
n = n | arr[1];
std::cout << n << std::endl;
```

There was some truncation if you leave the 'arr' array as char.

Comment: Wouldn't `unsigned char arr[] = { 0x0a, 0xc0 };` be easier?