# Java long byte length

Tags: java

If Java's *long* primitive data type is a 64-bit signed integer, then why do the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) state that the `static long` maximum value is 2^63-1? Is there a larger reason that affects other primitive data types similarly in Java?

I'm learning Java and am just genuinely curious about this disparity. Thank you.

Comment: The minimum value is not 0...

Comment: A signed value needs to be able to distuinguish between `x` and `-x`. That's why the maximum value is not the size.

Comment: What do you mean @assylias?

Comment: The mechanism is called "Two's complement".

Comment: What he means is that there are `long` values less than zero.  In fact, there are **more** `long` values less than zero than greater than zero!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: in any programming language, the Most Significant Bit will be the sign bit, which denotes the sign of the number. So in your question, for a 64-bit signed integer, leaving the MSB, the remaining 63 bits are used to denote the value of the integer. Which is why 2^63-1

Comment: @AshwinKKumar that is wrong. Java uses the "Two`s Complement" and does not just use the most significant bit for the sign (the fact that the msb is 1 for negative numbers is true but the remaining bits are not the same as for the positive number)

Comment: *"in any programming language, the Most Significant Bit will be the sign bit"* - Incorrect.  1) In a programming language with unsigned integers, the top bit is not the sign bit. 2) You are assuming the programming language uses the hardware-provided native (signed) integer representation.  In some languages, that is not always true ... or never true.   (Example of "never true" - the CLU programming language, which "stole" a bit for use by the GC to distinguish scalars from pointers.)

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement

Comment: Ahh. My bad, I went through the Java Documentation to clear things up. Shouldn't have assumed things.

Comment: I don't get the question - what disparity? *64-bit **signed** integer* ranges from `-2^63` to `+2^63-1` (-1 to count for `0`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java's `long` type is indeed a 64-bit integer, but it is also *signed*.

With 64-bit, you can represent 2^64 different numbers. If you ignore all the negative numbers, then the maximum value would be 2^64-1, and minimum will be 0. 0 plus all 2^64-1 positive numbers is 2^64 numbers in total.

However, if you consider all the negative numbers as well as the positives, about half of the 2^64 different numbers will be negative. Java just chose to represent 2^63 negative numbers, the number 0, and 2^63-1 positive numbers. If you add all these up, you get 2^64 total numbers.

```
2^63 + 1 + 2^63 - 1 = 2^64
       ^
       |
  this is the number zero
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just a range formula just like range for octal and hexadecimal numbers `2^n -1` 
different for signed and unsigned numbers. `2^n` and `2^n-1`(Range)