# Signed and unsigned char

Tags: c++, unsigned-char

Why are two char like `signed char` and `unsigned char` with the same value not equal?

```
char a = 0xfb; 
unsigned char b = 0xfb;
bool f;
f = (a == b); 
cout << f;
```

In the above code, the value of `f` is 0.
Why it's so when both `a` and `b` have the same value?

Comment: have u seen this warning in your compiler? `warning: overflow in conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from '251' to ''\37777777773'' [-Woverflow]
     char a=0xfb;` [see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b83589f0c4bb883e).

Comment: My code is running without any warning & giving output as 0;

Comment: Try enabling warnings. The value of `a` is `-5`. The value of `b` is `251`. They are not equal.

Comment: @raymondChen a is -5 -> a is probably -5

Comment: @Bathsheba The likelihood that OP is using a ones-complement or sign-magnitude system is vanishingly small.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Or non-existent in C++14! But note that the conversion is still implementation defined.

Comment: @Bathsheba I think it's not helpful to the OP to get into language-lawyering details. Let's try to explain the observed behavior.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I think you can do both in this case. My answer is hardly technical, no?

Comment: The number of systems where `CHAR_MAX` is not 127 and integers are not twos-complement is basically zero. No need to inject the possibility into a beginner discussion.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Rubbish. It's appropriate here to have a selection of answers. I really don't see your point. Do not (i) make assumptions about the OP and (ii) don't assume this entire page is targetted at the OP. And your comment above is ignorant. I have access to a machine where char, short, int, long, and long long are all the same size.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I'm curious. Is it a DSP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no arithmetic operators that accept integers smaller than `int`. Hence, both char values get promoted to `int` first, see [integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion)
 for full details.

`char` is signed on your platform, so `0xfb` gets promoted to `int(-5)`, whereas `unsigned char` gets promoted to `int(0x000000fb)`. These two integers do not compare equal.

On the other hand, the standard in [[basic.fundamental]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#1) requires that all char types occupy the same amount of storage and have the same alignment requirements; that is, they have the same object representation and all bits of the object representation participate in the value representation. Hence, `memcmp(&a, &b, 1) == 0` is `true`.

Answer (score 6):

The value of `f` and, in fact, the behaviour of the program, is *implementation-defined*.

In C++14 onwards<sup>1</sup>, for a `signed` `char`, and assuming that `CHAR_MAX` is `127`, `a` will probably be `-5`. Formally speaking, if `char` is `signed` and the number does not fit into a `char`, then the conversion is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

`b` is `251`.

For the comparison `a == b` (and retaining the assumption that `char` is a narrower type than an `int`) *both* arguments are converted to `int`, with `-5` and `251` therefore retained.

And that's `false` as the numbers are not equal.

Finally, note that on a platform where `char`, `short`, and `int` are all the same size, the result of your code would be `true` (and the `==` would be in `unsigned` types)! The moral of the story: **don't mix your types**.

---

<sup>1</sup> C++14 dropped 1's complement and signed magnitude `signed char`.

Comment: why -5? I calculated -3 like this: -127 + (251 - 127). Isn't that correct?

Comment: @pergy. No, 2's complement does not work that way. It's -5.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1049880/509868 (actually, that answer uses the value -5 as an example)

Comment: @anatolyg: Well you can't get much better than that!

Comment: "C++14 dropped 1's complement and signed magnitude signed char". I've checked the current draft standard, and haven't found this. Is this explicitly said, or can be inferred?

Answer (score 4):

- Value range for (signed) `char` is `[-128, 127]`. (C++14 drops -127 as the lower range).
- Value range for `unsigned char` is `[0, 255]`

What you're trying to assign to both of the variables is `251` in decimal. Since `char` cannot hold that value you will suffer a value overflow, as the following warning tells you.

> warning: overflow in conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from '251' to ''\37777777773'' [-Woverflow]

As a result `a` will probably hold value `-5` while `b` will be `251` and they are indeed not equal.

Comment: But at output both a and b are printing same symbol.

Comment: @T.g The printing mechanism for character types interprets the underlying bit pattern, not the numerical value of the variable. The representation is the same, but the values are different.

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks, I got it...but how the value -5 is assigned to a ..since 251 is not in range of [-128,127]

Comment: @T.g I've just asked the same under the other answer :) take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1049880/509868