# Why does toHexString have variable length?

Tags: java, type-conversion, hex

Why is it that toHexString prints different strings in what appears to be very specific circumstances? Printing a number below 0x80000000 works just fine. Adding 1 to that value and printing it works fine. But assigning that value directly does not print the same thing, instead I have to add an L to the end.

My guess is that it has to do with the fact that numeric literals are of type int by default, but I don't know this happens at 0x80000000 and not when crossing over 0xffffffff for instance.

```
long a = 0x7FFFFFFF;
System.out.println(java.lang.Long.toHexString(a)); // prints 7fffffff

a++;
System.out.println(java.lang.Long.toHexString(a)); // prints 80000000


long b = 0x80000000;
System.out.println(java.lang.Long.toHexString(b)); // prints ffffffff80000000

b=0x80000000L;
system.out.println(java.lang.Long.toHexString(b)); // prints 80000000
```

P.S. Why doesn't [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toHexString(long)) or [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/long_tohexstring.htm) say anything about how methods are implemented? Where can I find the implementation of the standard libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has nothing to do with the `toHexString` method, it's all about `int` vs `long` in Java, and binary representation of signed integers.

When you write

`long b = 0x7FFFFFFF;`

and

`long b = 0x80000000;`

the literal number on the right is interpreted as an `int` (32 bits). Now, in the second case that value overflows the (signed) integer positive range, its binary represantion has a `1` in the leftmost position, and hence the number is understood as negative (-2147483648). Afterwards, in the assignment, it's promoted to a (negative) long, so the extra 32 bits are filled with ones. That's why you see those "extra" `FFF...`

If you don't know about the binary representation of signed integers in Java, [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement)

Comment: I understand two's complement, but I don't know when I can safely omit the L at the end of a literal. I even mentioned that literals are inferred to be ints and that it had to do with that. But since I'm not passing a literal into the method I'm still confused. By incremting a, the extra f's from becoming a negative number don't appear. That is the part that confuses me.

Comment: Before you increment `a` , you have a long value (positive in this case), the literal has been promoted to 64 bits. Then, the increment corresponds to `a = a +1` but this sum is done as long (64 bits), so there is no overflow/crossing. Forget about the `toHexString` method . Try inserting a plain `System.out.printl(a)` and `System.out.printl(b)` to understand what is happening. To represent the number in hexa is good to get the binary representation, but it makes less evident if the number is positive or negative.