# C++ left shift operation

Tags: c++, bit-shift

Here is my code

```
int a=2147483647; 
int b= a<<1;
cout<<"a="<<a<<",  b="<<b;
```

The output I am getting is-
a=214783647, b=-2

Binary representation of **a** is

> 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111

By shifting it by 1 bit, it will change sign bit and replace LSB with 0. So, I think answer will be -ve and magnitude will be subtracted by 1 i.e 
-2147483646
But it is giving result as -2 . Please explain.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is “2's Complement”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your computer is using 2 complement for the signed value.
Unsigned shifted value is `0xFFFFFFFE`, which is -2 in 2 complement, not `-2147483647`.

Shifting is implementation defined in C.

BTW, `-2147483647` is `0x80000001` on such CPU.

Answer (score 2):

> **[expr.shift]/1** The value of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are zero-filled. ... if `E1` has a signed type and non-negative value, and `E1 × 2^E2` is representable in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type, then that value, converted to the result type, is the resulting value; otherwise, **the behavior is undefined**.

Emphasis mine. Your program exhibits undefined behavior.

---

Edit: Upon closer consideration, I no longer think it's undefined behavior. `2147483647*2` does fit into `unsigned int`, "the corresponding unsigned type" of `int`. Its conversion to `int` is not undefined, but merely implementation-defined. It's entirely reasonable for an implementation using two's complement to define this conversion so that `2147483647*2 == -2`, just reinterpreting the bit pattern, as other answers explained.

Comment: Note that the quoted paragraph is no longer in the C++ Standard. However, this sentence implies the same: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#pre-4.sentence-1.

Comment: Upon closer examination, I no longer think it's undefined behavior. `2147483647*2` does fit into `unsigned int`, "the corresponding unsigned type" of `int`. Its conversion to `int` is not undefined, but merely implementation-defined. It's entirely reasonable for an implementation using two's complement to define this conversion so that `2147483647*2 == -2`, just reinterpreting the bit pattern.

Comment: @DanielLangr The draft standard you cite [defines left shift thusly](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift#2): "The value of `E1 << E2` is the unique value congruent to `E1×2^E2` modulo `2^N`, where `N` is the width of the type of the result." It so happens that `-2 == 2147483647*2 modulo 2^32`. So I think the draft standard actually expanded the domain of shift operator, and made the original expression well-defined.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It did not. 2147483647 * 2 is 4294967294, which modulo 2^32 (N=32 is the width of the `int` type) is still 4294967294. And this number is not in the range of representable values for `int`.

Comment: @DanielLangr I'm not sure I follow. `-2` is the unique value of `int` type that is [congruent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Definition_of_congruence_relation) to 4294967294 modulo 2^32, is it not?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It's an interesting topic for discussion. The Standard says _the unique value congurent to `E1x2^E2` modulo `2^N`_. However, there is no such unique value, there is an infinite number of such congurent values, for which `((E1<<E2) - E1x2^E2)=k x 2^N` and `k` is an integer. So, which of them is _the_ unique value that the Standard mentions?

Comment: @DanielLangr I think it's clear that the standard means "unique value of the result type"; not value in the mathematical sense, as obviously there's an infinite number of them and the passage would become meaningless under such an interpretation. Among (the finite number of) values of `int` type, `-2` is in fact the only one congruent to 4294967294 modulo 2^32.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think I figured it out. The definition from http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift#2 belongs to the C++ Standard latest draft, which will become C++20. In C++20, two-complement representation of negative integers is required, therefore the left shift of a signed value that "overflows" is defined as well. In C++11, C++14, and C++17, the definition of left shift is different and makes this case undefined.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Anyway, I guess you are right, but I also asked a separate question about this issue to got more opinions. See here if you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55468807/580083. Of course, your answer is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a very long story behind.

Since int is a signed type, it means that the first bit is a sign and the whole system is two-complement.

so x = 0b 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0111 is x = -9
and for example x = 0b 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 is x = -1 and x = 0b 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 is 2

Learn more about [Two complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).