# Does C++20 well-define left shift for signed integers that "overflow"?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, bit-shift, c++20

In the current C++ Standard Draft, the left shift operator is defined as follows [[expr.shift]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift#2):

> The value of `E1 << E2` is **the unique value** congruent to `E1×2^E2` modulo `2^N`, where `N` is the width of the type of the result.

Consider `int E1 = 2^31-1 = 2'147'483'647`, `E2 = 1`, and `int` having 32 bits. Then there is *an infinite number of numbers congruent to* `E1×2^E2 = 4'294'967'294` modulo `2^N = 2^32`, namely, all the numbers `4'294'967'294 + k×2^32` where `k` is an arbitrary integer. Examples are `4'294'967'294` (`k=0`) or `-2` (`k=-1`).

I don't understand what the Standard means by **the unique value** out of these numbers. Does it mean *the unique value that can be represented by the resulting data type*? Then, I suppose the result is defined as `-2`. Is this interpretation correct?

Until C++20, the definition was different and this case would cause undefined behavior. I suppose the change is related to the mandatory 2's-complement representation of negative signed integers.

In fact, there is now no more requirement for `E1` to be non-negative. It therefore seems that `-1 << 1` is defined as `-2`. Is that right as well?

Comment: "In fact, there is now no more requirement for `E2` to be non-negative". In the link you provided, there is the comment "The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative". Did you mean `E1`, as in the example you gave? Or perhaps this has changed since you posted the question?

Comment: @deltacrux It was a typo, thanks for mentioning.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does it mean the unique value that can be represented by the resulting
>   data type

Yes. The set of numbers congruent to `E1×2^E2` modulo `2^N` is infinite, but there is only one value in any interval of size `2^N`, therefore there is only one value representable in an integer type of width `N`.

If we look in the ["p0907R1 Signed Integers are Two’s Complement" proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r1.html) we find a similar phrase with "unique representation" which makes this more clear:

> Conversion from signed to unsigned is always well-defined: the result
>   is the unique value **of the destination type** that is congruent to the
>   source integer modulo 2<sup>N</sup>.

> Then, I suppose the result is defined as `-2`. Is this interpretation
>   correct?

Yes

On x64 the equivalent asm instruction is [`shlx`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sarx:shlx:shrx) (logical shift left)

> I suppose the change is related to the mandatory 2-complement
>   representation of negative signed integers.

Correct. As was the case with unsigned types, now also signed types they mathematically represent equivalence classes (well, it's not clear to me how much this is true as it looks like they want to still keep some UB cases on overflow).

Comment: Important ist the word 'congruent' which is a well defined mathematical term:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Answer (score 3):

So we know that:

```
E1 = 2147483647
E2 = 1
N = sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT = 4 * 8 = 32
```

Let's compute `E1×2^E2 modulo 2^N` ([modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is the remainder of the division):

```
x = E1×2^E2 mod 2^N = 2147483647 * 2 ^ 1 mod 4294967296 = 4294967294 mod 4294967296 = 4294967294
```

Then we go to [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#basic.fundamental):

> For each value x of a signed integer type, the value of the
>   corresponding unsigned integer type congruent to x modulo  2 N  has
>   the same value of corresponding bits in its value representation.

and I think we also need:

> The base-2 representation of a value of signed integer type is the
>   base-2 representation of the congruent value of the corresponding
>   unsigned integer type.

That means, that `x = 4294967294` is equal to `x = -2` for `signed int`. So the result will be `-2`.

> It therefore seems that -1 << 1 is defined as -2. Is it right as well?

```
 (signed)-1 << 1 = 
 4294967295 << 1 = 
 4294967295 * 2 ^ 1 mod 4294967296 = 
 8589934590 mod 4294967296 = 
 4294967294 = 
 (signed)-2
```