# Static Assert unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, g++, static-assert

Here is the code which has unexpected behaviour:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace n1{
    namespace n2{
        enum comparator_t {
          LT = 0, /*!< less-than < */
          LE = 1, /*!< less-than-or-equal-to, i.e. <= */
        };
    }
}
int main(){
    int32_t const INF_VALUE = INT32_MAX >> 1;
    int32_t const MINUS_INF_VALUE = INT32_MIN >> 1; 
    
    int32_t const LT_INFINITY = (INF_VALUE << 1) | n1::n2::LT;
    int32_t const LE_MINUS_INFINITY = (MINUS_INF_VALUE << 1) | n1::n2::LE;

    int32_t const LE_ZERO = (0 << 1) | n1::n2::LE;
    
    static_assert(LE_ZERO != LT_INFINITY, "");
    static_assert(LE_ZERO != LE_MINUS_INFINITY, "");    
}
```

The above C++ code gives a compilation error:

> error: non-constant condition for static assertion

However, when the last line of the code is commented (`//static_assert(LE_ZERO != LE_MINUS_INFINITY, "");`), the code compiles properly. The definition of `LE_MINUS_INFINITY` and `INF_VALUE` look very similar, so why is the code not compiling?

Comment: Even for small examples, please [don't include that `<bits/stdc++.h>` header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h), it's *always* wrong.

Comment: What compiler is producing this objection?

Comment: As for your problem, please [build with extra warnings enabled](https://godbolt.org/z/qnM8abc83). That will indicate a major problem. Hint: For bitwise operations, always use *unsigned* integer types.

Comment: Is that the entire error message? Both GCC and Clang explain in plain English why they don't like the second assert. And interestingly, the code compiles with `-std=c++20`.

Comment: @user19584800 the output of command ```g++ --version``` is ```g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with this line:

```cpp
int32_t const LE_MINUS_INFINITY = (MINUS_INF_VALUE << 1) | n1::n2::LE;
```

Up until the C++20 Standard, left-bit-shifting a negative signed integer value is undefined behaviour. Your compiler (rightly) refuses to accept the result of that UB as a compile-time constant.

Changing to use the `-std=c++20` (or equivalent, for your compiler) fixes the issue. See on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/hT8oETYo3).

Comment: Note: C++20 added that integer values are two's-complement making the shift defined.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat For the purpose of constexpr implementation defined is bad.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow That fact that using 2's complement is mandatory since C++20 does not, of itself, make the difference between defined or undefined behaviour. There was still the issue of whether shifts on signed integers should be arithmetic or logical.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow It doesn't seem to be. It's `<<` that's problematic, if I only use `>>`, the code compiles.

Comment: @AdrianMole I don't think arithmetic vs logical shift was ever in question for two's-complement. The problem is that arithmetic shift of one's-complement and sign+magnitude give different results to two's-complement.

Comment: `0x8000'0000 << 1` and `0x4000'0000 << 1` is still UB, right? I.e. when the sign bit changes.

Comment: @Goswin Even that is well-defined by C++20. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55468807/10871073).

Comment: Which then means `x << 1` != `x * 2`.