# Casting a char to unsigned char

Tags: c++, casting, char, unsigned

There are many questions related to this but they answer conversion of char* to unsigned char*. What I want to ask is conversion of char to unsigned char :

If I cast ( C-style or static-cast ) a char to an unsigned char like :

`char c = 'A' ;
unsigned char uc = ( unsigned char ) c ;`

Can the integral value of `c` change during the cast ? 
As **char** is signed or unsigned, is implementation defined, so wherever it is **signed** , is it possible that the cast would change the integral value of the character ?

My Primary concern is for positive values. If I cast the 'above' way, is there a possibility of the values being changed?

Comment: What do you think happens when you cast a char containing a negative value to an unsigned char?

Comment: For positive values it won't change. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++14, `char` if `signed` **must** be 2's complement.

Therefore the cast from `signed char` to `unsigned char` and vice-versa **cannot** change the underlying bit pattern.