# Why is signed char min -128 and not -127?

Tags: c, binary

Singed numbers in memory are represented in such a way that the first bit defines a sign. I've taken a char as an example (and as a simpliest type to type), but this concerns other signed datatypes as well.

```
14 = 00001110
```

Since the first number is positive, the first bit is 0.
The max signed char is represented like this:

```
127 = 01111111
```

It seems to be reasonable to simply change the first bit to make it negative, but then the other 7 bits still can only represent the number of 127 (if do not take the first bit into account). How then is it possible to store -128?

Comment: The limits have been taken from <limits.h> C library, but generally that is about basics (informatics and all that stuff), not about the language itself

Comment: Can you confirm what language you are talking about?

Comment: Didn't I confirm?) I used C to get the limits

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is “2's Complement”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-128 would be represented as `10000000` (which *looks* like -0, but that would be a redundant way of representing 0).