# Why did I have to declare a long variable for bit mask?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

https://leetcode.com/problems/number-complement/

The following are two valid solutions for this problem, why did I run into an integer overflow in the first solution when I had the `mask` variable to be an int (instead of a long), and why was I able to get away with an int variable type for the `mask` in the second solution

```java
 public int findComplement(int num) {

    // Make a copy of the number for length estimation purposes , because we will begin mutating it
    // directly
    int input = num;

    // Use a power of two mask to bring 1 at every position and flip in stages using XOR
    for (long mask = 1; mask <= input; mask *= 2) {
      num = (int) (num ^ mask);
    }

    return num;
  }
```

```java
public int findComplement2(int num) {
        
    int save = num; 
    int mask = 1;
    
    while (save != 0) {
        num = num ^ mask;
        mask = mask << 1;
        save = save >> 1;
    }
    
    
   return num;
    
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement

Answer (score 1):

The way your condition in your `for` loop is set requires that the value for `mask` must be greater than the value of `input` to terminate. However, when you use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as the input, there will be no other `int` value greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which would stop the `for` loop. So your `for` loop will runs forever because

```
for(/* */, mask <= Integer.MAX_VALUE, /* */) {
}
```

will be always `true` in case the variable `mask` is of type `int` (or smaller).

To stop the `for` loop you have to use the type `long` for the variable `mask` so there is a chance that `mask <= input` will result in `false` in case the input value `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is used.

In your second method, you run in an integer overflow as well, as `mask` will jump from 1073741824 to -2147483648. However, in that case the variable `save` will be zero, terminating the `while` loop by the `save != 0` check. so the fact that `mask` is negative from an integer overflow has no consequences.