# Converting decimal to an 8 bit Twos Complement C++

Tags: c++, twos-complement

The assignment is to convert a decimal value to an 8-bit twos complement binary. The input needs to range between -128 & 127. Currently, my program only works for positive numbers. I am fairly new at coding so I've been stuck, and would appreciate any help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int DecimalToBinary(int dec);

int main() {
    int userInput;

    cout << "Enter a value: ";
    cin >> userInput;

    if (userInput >= -128 && userInput <= 127) {
        int dec = userInput;
        cout << userInput << " = ";
        DecimalToBinary(dec);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Enter a value between -128 and 127: ";
        cin >> userInput;
        if (userInput >= -128 && userInput <= 127)
        {
            int dec = userInput;
            cout << userInput << " = ";
            DecimalToBinary(dec);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int DecimalToBinary(int dec)
{
    int bin[1000] = {};     // array to store binary number

    int i = 0;
    while (dec > 0) {       //calculating the binary
        bin[i] = dec % 2;   //storing remainder
        dec = dec / 2;
        ++i;
    }

    // printing binary in 8 bit & reverse order
    int bits = 8;
    if (i > 8) {
        bits = 8 * ((i + 7) / 8);
    }
    for (int j = bits - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        cout << bin[j];
    }
    return dec;;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is “2's Complement”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement)

Comment: Isn't the program already doing what the assignment asks for: Taking an integer input, and ouputting it as an 8-bit binary value? Very likely the system you're on is a twos-complement system, so the integer input already is in the correct format.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution using stringstream and mask with explanations

#### [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

> In two's complement notation, a non-negative number is represented by its ordinary binary representation; in this case, the most significant bit is 0. Though, the range of numbers represented is not the same as with unsigned binary numbers. For example, an 8-bit unsigned number can represent the values 0 to 255 (11111111).

> However a two's complement 8-bit number can only represent positive integers from 0 to 127 (01111111), because the rest of the bit combinations with the most significant bit as '1' represent the negative integers −1 to −128.

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string DecimalToBinary(int n) {
    stringstream ss((n < 0) ? "1" : "0"); // the first bit, for any integer, indicates if its negative or not
    if (n < 0)
        n = -(n+1); // read about two complement!
    int mask = 1 << 6; // Since int8_t has only 8 bits you just need to have your mask initialized to 2^6 (equivalent to 0b01000000) as your initial mask that will help you to detect the 7 following bits, from left to right.

    while (mask) {
        ss << ((mask & n) ? "1" : "0"); // if the bit of the mask matches the bit of n then we add it to the string.
        mask >>= 1; // 0b01000000 becomes 0b00100000 and so on
    }
    return ss.str();
}
```

Also change:

```
cout << userInput << " = " << DecimalToBinary(dec) << "\n";
```

Alternatively, you can keep your approach with a buffer char array, but you only need 9 characters for its length: first char is the sign ('1' for negative and '0' for pos), then the 7 bits that makes the value, and the '\0' ending the string.

[image]

> The two's complement operation is the additive inverse operation, so negative numbers are represented by the two's complement of the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

int i_val = -128;
char ch = (char)i_val;

std::bitset<8> x(ch);
std::cout << x << '\n';
    // or other way
    std::string s;

    for (int i = sizeof(char) * 8 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if ((a >> i) & 1) s += '1';
        else s += '0';
    }
    std::cout << s << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```