# ~ operator in python 3 ouput a amount that I did not expect. What is the reason for this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

My understanding was that `~` ***inverts all bits*** on the value specified.
the binary representation of `10` is `00001010`.
If I invert all the bits I get `11110101 = 235`.
Why is `-11` displayed? Where am I going wrong?

```
a = 10
print(a)
print(~a)   
# Output -11
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: In two's complement, bitwise negation of a positive number N gives you `-N-1`. See [What is “2's Complement”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1049722/3890632)

Comment: What makes you think Python is using an unsigned 8-bit representation?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Most students learn the basics of base 2 natural numbers long before they learn about two's complement (which is more of an implementation issue). It is the sort of thing many students would assume even without realizing that they are making an assumption.

Comment: Thank you all. I read the documents you suggested and I understand know. Your feedback is much appreciated!