# Why does T-SQL command "Select ~ (tilde) 0" give "-1"

Tags: sql-server

In SSMS, "SELECT ~ 0" gives -1 as the result. Similar results with other numbers too. I would like to know why.

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-not-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is “2's Complement”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`~` is [Bitwise NOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-not-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

`0` is `0x00000000`, `~0` is `0xFFFFFFFF` and since `int` is signed, and negative numbers are stored using [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

`select cast(0xFFFFFFFF as int)`

outputs

`-1`