# What is the working mechanism of inv() in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

why the answer is -5 ?

it should be 11 because all zeroes will be ones and all ones will be zeroes.

`var v = 4 //0100`
`println("bit Inverse = "+(v.inv()))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is “2's Complement”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement)

Comment: @Sam i did 2's complement of 4 as unsigned number and result of 4 (binary = 0100) was 1100 (base10 = 12). When i did this for signed number, result was -4 in base 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the two's complement system, the most-significant digit on the left represents a negative value - in this case, `-8`.

```
-8 4 2 1
```

So the largest *positive* value you can represent with 4 bits is `0111`, or *7*.

```
-8 4 2 1
 0 1 1 1 = 0 + 4 + 2 + 1
```

The largest *negative* value is `1000`, or *-8*.

```
-8 4 2 1
 1 0 0 0  = -8 + 0 + 0 + 0
```

And the inverse of `0100` is `1011`, which gives us

```
-8 4 2 1
 1 0 1 1  = -8 + 0 + 2 + 1
```

which is `-5`!